# How to remove Picture Box background after picture box?

Tags: c#

How to remove that picturebox background after picture box?
I want to make when a mouse hover some picturebox slot, it will show tooltip text. But it was very disturbing picture box slot and must be made invisible.

[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeTbj.png)

Thank you :)

Comment: Huh, what do you want to hide??? After reading the question a few times and looking at the image I still don't understand.

Comment: I would like the white part was missing, but can still hover in the picture of the white box. If I make it visible = false, the result hover mouse will not work.

Comment: even with some imagination, it is difficult to understand what you need to achieve. make the tooltip show elsewhere, so it would not cover up any part of the crafting table? or make the 3 x 3 grid transparent in the background? please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, i want to make the 3x3 grid transparent.

Comment: I still don't understand anything. Really. Nothing. I don't know what is what in the image and I don't know anything about what you have done. Nor what the tooltip has to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Controls have a Visbile property, if you set it to fase, the control will not be visibe anymore.

Or is your issue when to make it invisible? You may need to handle the MouseLeave event, and place this code there:

```
    private void OnMouseLeavePicturebox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: I would like the white part was missing, but can still hover in the picture of the white box. If I make it visible = false, the result hover mouse will not work.

Comment: Would it help if you can just remove the control? There a re a number of questions regrding this topic, so it is not very difficult to find some solutions.

Comment: Yes, i just want to remove that white backcolor.

Comment: I've never done it, but you can remove controls completely. Another solution might be to set a proper background color to the picturebox. Not sure if this works, just try.